# Insert multiple rows without duplicating them - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute this query nut it seems that it returns errors:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`,`path`) VALUES ('TEST 1' , 'test-1'),('TEST 2' , 'test-2'),('TEST 3' , 'test-3')
WHERE (`name`,`path`) NOT IN (SELECT `name`,`path` FROM `categories`);
```

Any help with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: You could add a unique key and use `insert ignore into ...` to insert the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you are attempted is implemented using syntax like this:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`,`path`)
     SELECT name, path
     FROM (SELECT 'TEST 1' as name, 'test-1' as path UNION ALL
           SELECT 'TEST 2', 'test-2' UNION ALL
           SELECT 'TEST 3' , 'test-3'
          ) t
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM categories c
                       WHERE c.name = t.name and c.path = t.path
                      );
```

However, you should be doing the checking in the database with a unique index.  So the better solution is to do the insert and just have:

```
create unique index idx_categories_name_path on categories(name, path)
```

With an `insert` like:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`,`path`)
     SELECT name, path
     FROM (SELECT 'TEST 1' as name, 'test-1' as path UNION ALL
           SELECT 'TEST 2', 'test-2' UNION ALL
           SELECT 'TEST 3' , 'test-3'
          ) t
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name);
```

Comment: The thing is the values can goes to 200 or more rows! is it ok if I proceed like u're answer ?

Comment: @user3350731 . . . There is no problem at all with handling 200 values using either method.